# Facebook sdk posting image to wall

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to set up a method posting an image to the users facebook wall, but what I have set up isn't working.

here's the code I have, would anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am able to get the users name and picturee.t.c but cannot post. Do I need to add any additional permissions? I have not set any up yet.

```
try {
                    outputphoto = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            this.getContentResolver(), mImageUri);

                    int WIDTH = outputphoto.getWidth();
                    int HEIGHT = outputphoto.getHeight();

                    Log.d("WIDTH", String.valueOf(WIDTH));
                    Log.d("HEIGHT", String.valueOf(HEIGHT));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Request.Callback uploadPhotoRequestCallback = new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            // post error
                        } else {
                            String idRploadResponse = (String) response
                                    .getGraphObject().getProperty("id");
                            if (idRploadResponse != null) {

                                String fbPhotoAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid="
                                        + idRploadResponse;
                            } else {
                                // error
                            }

                        }
                    }
                };

                Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                        Session.getActiveSession(), outputphoto,
                        uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
                Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); // <-- THIS IS
                                                                // IMPORTANT
                parameters.putString("message", "My message");
                // add more params here
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the publish_actions permission in order to upload a photo.